# How can I extend a DataAnnotation attribute and have client side validation work?

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, model-binding, unobtrusive-validation

In a large number of places on my model, I have a property `public int CarrotLength {get; set;}` I want to put a `[Range(5, 100)]` attribute on it.

Rather than have to specify this millions of times for every `CarrotLength` property, because the carrot length might change, it makes sense to make a `[CarrotLength]` attribute instead so I can just change the values 5 and 10 in one place.

I made a `public class CarrotLengthAttribute : RangeAttribute` and call the base class with 5, 100. However the client side unobtrusive javascript validation doesn't trigger.

Is there a way to make it work? Possibly I need to register the attribute somehow?

My unobtrusive javascript validation works for normal attributes, as well as custom ones that I have created.

If it's not possible I will just define the values as constants and reference them as `[Range(MYCONSTS.CARROTLENGTHMIN...)]` but I think it's nicer to have a custom attribute.

Answer (score 0):

Try customing the attribute class that inherits from the `ValidationAttribute` and `IClientModelValidator` like below :

```
public class AgeRangeAttribute: ValidationAttribute , IClientModelValidator
{
    protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        var  age = Convert.ToInt32(value.ToString());

        if (age<5||age>100)
        {
            return new ValidationResult(GetErrorMessage());
        }
        return ValidationResult.Success;
    }
    public string GetErrorMessage()
    {
        return $"Age must be between 5 and 100.";
    }

    public void AddValidation(ClientModelValidationContext context)
    {
        context.Attributes.Add("data-val", "true");
        context.Attributes.Add("data-val-age", GetErrorMessage());
    }
}
```

Add a new JavaScript file named `AgeValidate.js` into the wwwroot folder `"/lib/jquery-validation-unobtrusive/AgeValidate.js"` :

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod("age",
function (value, element, param) {

    if (value < 5 || value > 100) {
        return false;
    }
    else {
        return true;
    }
});
jQuery.validator.unobtrusive.adapters.addBool("age");
```

The above code adds a method to jQuery validation library. It uses addMethod() method to specify our own validation function. The validation function receives the value entered in the age textbox. It then performs the validation and returns a boolean value.

Reference the AgeValidate.js in _ValidationScriptsPartial.cshtml

```
<environment include="Development">
   <script src="~/lib/jquery-validation/dist/jquery.validate.js"></script>
   <script src="~/lib/jquery-validation-unobtrusive/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js"> 
   </script>
   <script src="~/lib/jquery-validation-unobtrusive/AgeValidate.js"></script>
</environment>
```

Add the below code in your view

```
@section Scripts {
   @{await Html.RenderPartialAsync("_ValidationScriptsPartial");}
}
```

For more details on customizing client-side validation , you could refer to the official documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/validation?view=aspnetcore-2.2#custom-client-side-validation

Comment: Sure, I've done that for my own attributes but I was hoping there would be an easy way to use the existing attributes just in a pre-defined way. It looks like the `const` approach might be the only way then without spending a lot of effort making a custom attribute for each.

Comment: I'd add that if it is possible it'd be good for flexible attributes too, for example `[DateMustBeInThePast]` which calls the base with `DateTime.Now` or a dynamic number, which gives more incentive to see if there's a way to hook into the existing stuff without rolling my own custom javascript